# margin-right of inside elements by different directions does not work fine

Tags: html, css

i have to use different of direction (RTL/LTR) on elements. but margin-right does not works fine.

here are html codes:

```css
.divofitemprj {
  background-color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.divprjbottom23 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divofitemprj" align="center" dir="ltr" style=" overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="divprjbottom23" style="background-color:#a93432;" align="right" dir="rtl">
    this is a RTL text. this is a test. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text.
  </div>

</div>
```

it does not display margin-right of element.

Comment: The attribute `align` is not supported in HTML5 and is what mess things up here, so remove those and it work just fine

Comment: As a note, in Chrome I noticed it still gets applied though, and as **style attribute overrides any style set globally**, your margin is simply overridden. If you check in Firefox, your code works just fine as is.

Comment: @LGSon , so I expect margin works fine. Chrome can not change my codes. i think it is a Bug.

Answer (score -1):

margin-right does not work because of the mess in your code:

1. If all margins for `.divprjbottom23` are equal, there is short hand:

   .divprjbottom23 {
     margin: 10px;
     color: #fff;
   }
2. Don't use inline styles. Now your `.divofitemprj` has `overflow: hidden;` and `overflow: auto;` at the same time. It is confusing.

```css
.divofitemprj {
  background-color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.divprjbottom23 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #a93432;
}
```

```html
<div class="divofitemprj" dir="ltr">
  <div class="divprjbottom23" dir="rtl">
    this is a RTL text. this is a test. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Just clean up the code, remove [usupported](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp) attributes and it will work.

Comment: you use padding, i can do this also, but i need to know what is it problem?

Comment: So, write it in your question

Answer (score -2):

Use padding in the container.

```css
.divofitemprj {
      background-color: #555;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 40%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .divprjbottom23 {
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="divofitemprj" align="center" dir="ltr" style=" overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="divprjbottom23" style="background-color:#a93432;" align="right" dir="rtl">
        this is a RTL text. this is a test. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text. this is a RTL text.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: OP is asking why `margin-right` doesn't work, not what to do instead.

Comment: ok. I understand wrong. Just add display:inline-block to .divprjbottom23

Comment: @LGSon , i agree with u